# Should I do my own serialization of objects before storing them in ASP.NET 2.0 session state?

Tags: asp.net

I know, I know; don't store objects in session state. But...

Sections of our web application allow a user to define all sorts of criteria for viewing the results of data analysis:

- sorting (multiple columns)
- multiple filters
- highlight criteria
- column selection

I want to keep all these criteria handy as the user comes and goes to the analysis pages. I currently have objects that have lists of each type of criteria.

Here are my options:

- "Flatten" the object model, storing only the attributes of all the different criteria that I need. My concern with this option is that there could be many (dozens and dozens) of attributes.
- The classes are all marked as serializable. I could just plop them in session state and retrieve when needed. (Blech)
- Serialize the objects myself to something like JSON and store the JSON string in session.

Has anyone tried something like the third option and had success with it?

Comment: Session would see a JSON encoded data as just string data right?  Session["MyCoolJsonObject"] = Json.Encode(obj).   Wouldn't that just be a string at the end of the day?  What about storing their sorting,filtering, options in session as Dictionary objects or as bitmasks?